# Java - Good way to obtain path in Breadth First Search?

Tags: java, algorithm, breadth-first-search

I have worked on this the whole day and cannot think of a good solution. I am to implement a breadth first search algorithm in order to solve a sliding puzzle. Here are the relevant parts of my code so far. (I have yet to test if it works since it is incomplete)
So far, this code is expected to traverse through all the possibilities and arrive at the goal. However, I cannot think of a way to record that path from initial to goal state.

```
private void addToQueue(PuzzleState nextPS) {
    if (notVisitedAndNotNull(nextPS))
        queue.add(nextPS);
}

private void solveByBFS() {
    queue.clear();
    queue.add(this.initialState);
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while(!queue.isEmpty()) { //TODO create a way to backtrack and get a path
        if (queue.size() > maxQueueSize)
            maxQueueSize = queue.size();
        this.currentState = queue.poll();

        if (this.currentState.equals(finalState)) { //TODO check if cannot progress any further and terminate
            System.out.println("Successful! Ending Time: " + startTime);
            return;
        }
        visited.add(this.currentState);

        this.addToQueue(this.currentState.moveUp());
        this.addToQueue(this.currentState.moveDown());
        this.addToQueue(this.currentState.moveRight());
        this.addToQueue(this.currentState.moveLeft());

    }
    return;
}
```

So I want a way to back track and get from the goal node to the initial state, reverse the path, and then print it out in a list.

Here is the data structure I am using:

```
public class SimplePuzzleState implements PuzzleState{

private int rowSz;
private int sz;
private int zeroPos;
private int[] gameState;

@Override
public void configureState(int[] gameState) {
    rowSz = (int) Math.sqrt(gameState.length);
    sz = gameState.length;
    zeroPos = PuzzlePropertyUtility.findZeroPosition(gameState); 
    this.gameState = gameState;
}

@Override
public PuzzleState moveUp() { 
    if (zeroPos <= rowSz - 1) {
        return null;
    }
    this.swap(zeroPos, zeroPos - rowSz);
    return this.createNewUpdatedState();
}

@Override
public PuzzleState moveDown() {
    if (zeroPos >= sz - rowSz) {
        return null;
    }
    this.swap(zeroPos, zeroPos + rowSz);
    return this.createNewUpdatedState();
}

@Override
public PuzzleState moveLeft() {
    if (zeroPos % rowSz <= 0) {
        return null;
    }
    this.swap(zeroPos, zeroPos - 1);
    return this.createNewUpdatedState();
}

@Override
public PuzzleState moveRight() {
    if (zeroPos % rowSz >= rowSz -1) {
        return null;
    }
    this.swap(zeroPos, zeroPos + 1);
    return this.createNewUpdatedState();
}

@Override
public boolean isEqual(PuzzleState other) { 
    if (other != null) {
        if (this.getStateArray() instanceof int[] && other.getStateArray() instanceof int[])
            return (Arrays.equals(this.getStateArray(), other.getStateArray()));
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public int[] getStateArray() {
    return gameState;
}

private void swap(int pos1, int pos2) {
    int temp = this.gameState[pos1];
    this.gameState[pos1] = this.gameState[pos2];
    this.gameState[pos2] = temp;
}

private PuzzleState createNewUpdatedState() {
    PuzzleState newState = new SimplePuzzleState();
    newState.configureState(this.getStateArray());
    return newState;
}
```

}

Here is the PuzzleState Interface:

```
public interface PuzzleState {

public void configureState(int[] gameState);

PuzzleState moveUp();

PuzzleState moveDown();

PuzzleState moveLeft();

PuzzleState moveRight();



boolean isEqual(PuzzleState other);

int[] getStateArray();
```

}

I have thought about adding an attribute to SimplePuzzleState to include a parent node.
However, I cannot modify the interface which it implements since my instructor does not allow that. Therefore, I cannot backtrack using a linked list method. Are there any smart ways to record the correct path? In the end, my instructor wants me to print a list containing enums which represent the movements. So I have to figure how to map the enums to functions `moveUp`, `moveDown` etc.

Thank you in advance. I apologize for posting so much code, but I really need advice on which direction I should take.

Comment: Is it `SimplePuzzleState` that you can't modify or just `PuzzleState`?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I can modify SimplePuzzleState. However, in the JUnit test I am suppose to pass, PuzzleState is passed in. For instance, PuzzleState ps = new SimplePuzzleState();. Therefore, if I added an extra method to get the parent node, I could not access that.

Comment: Could you post the `PuzzleState` interface then? I hate to suggest a cast, but if something's broken (i.e., no suitable interface method)...

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Its posted. So far I am thinking of HashMap. Or maybe squeezing a parentNode attribute somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea.  If you can't add parent pointers to the states, then just maintain a `HashMap` with the same information called something like `previous`.  When you create the four 
child states, add mappings from the parent to these four.

```
// A map to hold parent relations.   
HashMap<SimplePuzzleState, SimplePuzzleState> previous = new HashMap<>();

...

// Now change the add function.
private void addToQueue(PuzzleState parentPS, PuzzleState nextPS) {
    if (notVisitedAndNotNull(nextPS)) {
        queue.add(nextPS);
        previous.add(nextPS, parentPS);
        nextPS.updateParent(this); // and update where we got from
    }
}

// Then update the calls to match:
this.addToQueue(currentState, this.currentState.moveUp());
...
```

When you find the goal, trace back to the start using the hash just as you would the parent pointers.

```
    if (this.currentState.equals(finalState)) { 
        System.out.println("Successful! Ending Time: " + startTime);
        System.out.println("Path back to start:");
        PuzzleState state = currentState;
        do {
          state.print();
          state = previous.get(state);
        } while (state != null);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to `SimplePuzzleState` another field called `gotHereFrom` and when you call `addToQueue()` update this field (per each item). When you're done, instead if printing "successful" and `return;` start iterating back according to `gotHereFrom` and print the nodes all the way back:

```
public class SimplePuzzleState implements PuzzleState{

    private int rowSz;
    private int sz;
    private int zeroPos;
    private int[] gameState;
    private SimplePuzzleState gotHereFrom; // add this guy
    ...

    protected void updateParent(SimplePuzzleState gotHereFrom) {
        this.gotHereFrom = gotHereFrom;
    }
    ...
}
```

and:

```
private void addToQueue(PuzzleState nextPS) {
    if (notVisitedAndNotNull(nextPS)) {
        queue.add(nextPS);
        nextPS.updateParent(this); // and update where we got from
    }
}
```

iterating the results:

```
...
if (this.currentState.equals(finalState)) { //TODO check if cannot progress any further and terminate
     System.out.println("Successful! Ending Time: " + startTime);
     String path = "";
     while (gotHereFrom != null) {
         path += " -> " + gotHereFrom;
         gotHereFrom = gotHereFrom.getGotHereFrom();
     }
     System.out.println(path);
     return;
}
```